# SPOJ is giving TLE for this solution of ROCK

Tags: optimization, algorithm, c, programming-challenge

I am solving [ROCK](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ROCK/) problem on SPOJ. I have used bottom up dynamic programming approach for this problem. Time complexity for this is \$O(n^3)\$.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define MAX 210
#define NEG_INFINITY -1000

int sellable(int a[MAX], int i, int j)
{
    int index,sweet=0,sour=0;
    for(index=i;index<=j;index++)
    {
        if(a[index])
            sweet++;
        else
            sour++;
    }
    if(sweet>sour)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int test_cases,i,j,k,length,l;
    int number,cost;
    int a[MAX];
    int m[MAX][MAX];
    char buffer[MAX];

    for(scanf("%d",&test_cases);test_cases>0;test_cases--)
    {       

        scanf("%d",&number);
        for(i=0;i<number;i++)
            for(j=0;j<number;j++)
                m[i][j]=NEG_INFINITY;
        scanf("%s",&buffer);
        for(i=0;i<number;i++)
        {
            a[i]=buffer[i]-'0';
            m[i][i]=a[i];
        }
        for(l=2;l<=number;l++)
        {       
            for(i=0;i<number-l+1;i++)
            {
                j=i+l-1;
                for(k=i;k<j;k++)
                {
                    if(sellable(a,i,j))
                        cost=j-i+1;
                    else
                        cost=m[i][k]+m[k+1][j];
                    if(cost>m[i][j])
                    {
                        m[i][j]=cost;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",m[0][number-1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you please suggest an alternative approach for this problem, or if any changes can be made in my code?

Comment: The constraints scream \$O(n^3)\$, so I would look into potential constant optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you call `sellable` may amount to a 4-th degree complexity. The very smart compiler may notice that it is a pure function, and optimize it out of the inner loop, but I wouldn't rely on it. So, one obvious optimization is to rephrase it as

```
if (sellable(a, i, j)) {
    cost = j - i + 1;
} else {
    cost = m[i][j];
    for (k = i; k < j; k++) {
        cost = max(cost, m[i][k] + m[k+1][j]);
}
m[i][j] = max(m[i][j], cost);
```

Still, `sellable` contributes to the cubic complexity. With a one-time linear investment you can make it into a constant time. Collect accumulated sums [0, i) of the input array; then `sellable` becomes just

```
return (a[j] - a[i]) * 2 > (j - i);
```

The mandatory CR note on the variable names: one letter identifiers make it really hard to follow the code, even as simple as this. I would recommend to use `length, seg_start, seg_end` instead of `l, i, j` respectively. `number` is just meaningless; `size` sounds better.

Then, I'd highly recommend to interpret `length` as *length* (not *length + 1* as your code does).

Finally, please don't be shy on spaces.

Comment: Only the first change itself lowered my running time by multitudes. Now I understand how I had put forth order just by messing up the order of execution. Thanks a lot for such precise answer. I have lot to learn.